# Set Mailable header via a trait?

Tags: laravel, email, header, swiftmailer

I'm creating a Laravel package that would benefit from the use of emails. When a user would use my package they would want to email a file created by the package, but also set some custom headers for the email.

In an ideal solution, I would like to have a trait that the developer could simply `use` on their mailable class and it would automatically set the header for that email without any additional code. Is this something that is even possible via the use of a trait?

Some solutions have suggested adding headers to mailables by putting this in the `build` method:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
    $headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('mime', 'text/calendar');
});
```

But is there some way to have my own custom trait piggy-back on the `build` method of the Mailable that is using it WITHOUT having to write it in the Mailable class itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION USING TRAITS**

The only way to be able to do that with a trait would be defining the `build` method in your trait and make your user define another function instead of `build` such that you have the direct manipulation of the function actually used by `Mailable` class.

So your trait would be:

```
trait IsMailable {


     public function build()
     {
          $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
              $headers = $message->getHeaders();
              $headers->addTextHeader('mime', 'text/calendar');
          });

          if(!method_exists($this, 'buildMail')) throw \Exception('buildMail is not defined!');
          return $this->buildMail();
      }



}
```

So your user will have to define the method `buildMail` instead of `build`.

**OPTIMAL SOLUTION**

The optimal solution, IMHO, would be extending the class `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` redefining the method `send` and making the end user implement this newly defined class instead of `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable`.

So your class would be:

```
class Mailable extends \Illuminate\Mail\Mailable {

    /**
    * Send the message using the given mailer.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer  $mailer
    * @return void
    */
    public function send(MailerContract $mailer)
    {
        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
            $headers = $message->getHeaders();
            $headers->addTextHeader('mime', 'text/calendar');
        });

        parent::send($mailer);
    }
}
```

Doing that your user can use the `build` method as it would do using the standard `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` class but the end result would be that your class is piggybacking the additional information that you actually need.